# What diagram should be used to represent algorithm logic

Tags: javascript, algorithm, uml, diagram

I have this recursive function:

```
function inline(o) {
    return objEntries(o).reduce(function (result, item) {
        var key = item[0];
        var val = item[1];

        if (val instanceof Object) {
            objEntries(inline(val)).forEach(function (subItem) {
                var subKey = subItem[0];
                var subVal = subItem[1];

                result[key + '.' + subKey] = subVal;
            });
        } else {
            result[key] = val;
        }
        return result;
    }, {});
}

function objEntries(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) {
        return [key, obj[key]];
    });
}
```

that takes an object and inlines its properties. For example, this:

```
var o = {some: {prop:5}}
```

becomes this:

```
var o = {"some.prop": 5};
```

I want to represent how it's working visually. What diagrams or notations can I use? Can somebody please provide small example based on the function I outlined?

Comment: You should use sequence diagram

Comment: It seems to turn out that the answer to your question is more opinion based than scientific.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, it may well be so, just didn't where else to ask

Comment: Who will be reading / consuming the diagram?  Is it for a textbook?  Is it to demonstrate how deep the stack can get?  The purpose will help determine the appropriate visualization.

Comment: Yes, it's for educational purposes to explain the general idea of the parts of the algorithm

Comment: This puts things in a very different light. Why didn't you include that in the question?

Comment: I didn't realize it was relevent

Answer (score 2):

You won't. UML is very good for abstraction. But once it comes to algorithms it's worth nothing. Don't try to use sequence diagrams and fragments, although you might present algorithms. There is some kind of fissure between UML models and code and best is to not bridge that with UML. If you describe the goals abstractly with UML and leave the rest to the coder, this is by far the best approach.

P.S. I had been dreaming of graphical programming in the 90s. We had 3 and 4GL but what do you see today in practice? Even more C-like stuff. Good luck for Alf, but it will probably also end in fresh cat juice.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with Thomas. Alf is a new programming language for UML that has functional, OO, and parallel processing baked in by default. It generates activity diagrams.

Even if you don't use Alf, activities can call themselves recursively. Activity diagrams are just harder to draw than Alf is to write. Alf is extremely compact and powerful.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically Activity diagram is capable of presenting algorithm logic.

However this should be still done at some abstraction level. It doesn't make sense to document each line of code using UML or you'll end up in programming using UML and then you'll have to look for a tool that will convert your "UML code" into "regular" code (or UML compiler).